Javascript React app "fetch" returning 'undefined' on reload from browser, but returning data when reloading from API
I have a component that pulls a json object from github
async function getQueryJson(URL) {
  await fetch(URL) // This gets the git commits
    .then((res) => res.json()) //Converts it to a JSON
    .then(
      (result) => {
        setCommits(result) // This puts the JSON containing the commits made to gitlocale into state
        console.log('Outputting value of GQJ')
        console.log(commits)
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('Error in fetch: ' + error)
      },
    )
}

which is called within the UseEffect portion of my React code to populate a State with an array of JSON objects.
useEffect(() => {
  var userObject = {}
  getQueryJson(githubCommits)
})

My issue is that when I first refresh the page, the the "commits" returns as "undefined" - if I change my code in my IDE which reloads the page, the "commits" returns an array of JSON and the code executes properly.
To complicate matters further, if I output (res.json()) to the console, I receive the JSON object in all circumstances regardless of whether my state is set to undefined, which makes me nervous about the execution.
Am I correctly using the async fetch function?
I don't think I need to perform this twice. It has the json object,but on a first visit it does not process the json.
I have removed the async/await portion, which did not affect functionality.
I have moved the results to another state, which receives  the undefined/json object the same, so it's not being incidentally initialized multiple times
I have attempted to pull the JSON independently from the fetch, which didn't work.

Since getQueryJson() is async, might you need to await it when you call it?

@mykaf awaiting it is pointless since it's only called for a side-effect and it's in a useEffect in a React app

Does your page crash when commits is undefined? You might just be doing console.log(commits) too soon. After you use a setState, the actual state isn't instantly set, but React sets it later on.

@GABRIELRGARCIA-AVILES
Yes, that's it. (It really crashes when it gets to a .map that relies on commits, but that's a result of the primary issue and not the primary issue)
That might be the rub- if I console.log(results) instead of the console.log(commits), I'm getting the correct json object.
Sounds like the issue is with my state assignment.

Unrelated to your problem: What are the differences between JSON and JavaScript object? The comment //Converts it to a JSON is wrong. It converts JSON to a JavaScript object.

You are trying to console.log(commits) right after it is set. Unlike regular variables, states are not set instantly. If you want to make an operation on the commits state when it ACTUALLY changes, it is better to use a hook like useEffect to trigger when commits is set.
// Ex:
useEffect (() => {
  // your code
}, [commits]);


This was the solution- I created two useEffects, one that ran on changes of Commit to display the information, and one that ran at component render to pull the data from github.
I'm now pulling all the information, and have a much better understanding of useEffect.
Thank you, everyone, for your assistance.
